# High precision in C#

Tags: c#, precision

I need some library to work with high precision double in C#.

I've searched and found some useful libraries like GMP, MPFR and C++ wrapper for MPFR, but none of them has interface for C#.

Could you please help me? :)

Sorry for my bad english (:

Comment: A quick google search reveals at least [one](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/) C# wrapper for GMP. It looks all right, give it a try :)

Comment: yes, i saw it, but this wrapper works only with integer, i need floating point numbers..

Comment: BigRational didn't make it into the .NET framework, only its code was published.  http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BigRational

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic.

I've used [W3b.Sine](http://sine.codeplex.com/) and I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a friend make [this](http://mpfr.codeplex.com/) mpfr wrapper for me. If you know Mpfr it should react pretty similarly.

Comment: [Context is preferred for posted links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).